# Apply a function to a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, functional-programming

I would like to apply a function (called **offline_optimize**) to a list of inputs. Each item in the list is a dictionary with 14 key-value pairs. The list consists of 12 dictionaries.

```
# This works
results = [offline_optimize(**input) for input in inputs]

# This doesn't
results = map(offline_optimize, *inputs)
```

> TypeError: offline_optimize() takes exactly 14 arguments (12 given)

**inputs** is a list of dictionaries. More precisely, the list consists of 12 dictionaries.

The function **offline_optimize** takes 14 arguments.

How can I use the **map** function on a list of dictionaries, when the dictionaries need to be unpacked (using the double-star syntax **) to 14 arguments to be accepted by the function **offline_optimize**?

I would like to avoid list comprehensions, if possible.

Comment: Change the function signature of `offline_optimize` so that it accepts a variable number of keyword arguments.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Could you give a brief example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list`

Return a list of the results of applying the function to the items of
the argument sequence(s).  **If more than one sequence is given, the
function is called with an argument list consisting of the corresponding
item of each sequence, substituting None for missing values when not all
sequences have the same length.**  If the function is None, return a list of
the items of the sequence (or a list of tuples if more than one sequence).

I think the effect is best illustrated by mocking out `inputs` and `offline_optimize`:

```
import string


inputs = [dict([(s, i) for i, s in enumerate(string.letters[:14])])] * 12

def offline_optimize(*args, **kwargs):
    return [("args", args),
            ("args_count", len(args)),
            ("kwargs", kwargs),
            ("kwargs_count", len(kwargs))]
```

What `inputs` look like:

```
>>> print len(inputs), len(inputs[0]), inputs[0]
12 14 {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 4, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F': 5, 'I': 8, 'H': 7, 'K': 10, 'J': 9, 'M': 12, 'L': 11, 'N': 13}
```

You do this:

```
>>> mapped = map(offline_optimize, *inputs)
>>> print len(mapped), mapped[0]
14 [('args', ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')), ('args_count', 12), ('kwargs', {}), ('kwargs_count', 0)]
```

You want to do this:

```
>>> mapped = map(lambda x: offline_optimize(**x), inputs)
>>> print len(mapped), mapped[0]

12 [('args', ()), ('args_count', 0), ('kwargs', {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 4, 'D': 3, 'G': 6, 'F': 5, 'I': 8, 'H': 7, 'K': 10, 'J': 9, 'M': 12, 'L': 11, 'N': 13}), ('kwargs_count', 14)]
```

You really want to use list comprehensions and to avoid functions with 14 keyword parameters.

Comment: Thanks, the ''map(lambda x: offline_optimize(**x), inputs)'' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, I'm assuming that `offline_optimize()` has a function signature something like the following:

```
def offline_optimize(arg1, arg2, maybe_arg3=some_default_value, ...):
    some_function(arg1)
    some_function(arg2, maybe_arg3)
    # etc.
```

Change your function definition to:

```
def offline_optimize(**kwargs):
    some_function(kwargs.get('arg1'))
    some_function(kwargs.get('arg2'), kwargs.get('maybe_arg3', some_default_value))
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was not aware of the 'get' function, especially in conjunction with 'some_default_value'. Still, the anonymous function from @SimonPantzare did the job.